# Exclude rows having 'NA' getting in any subsetting

Tags: r, subset, na

The data has a character column with the string 'NA' also being in it. If I do a subset of the data based upon that column I get those rows having 'NA' in that column. And all such rows gets filled with NA replacing the actual data.

Given below a sample of the data:

sample.csv

```
SYMBOL,SERIES,CLOSE,TIMESTAMP
A2ZMES,EQ,10.8,4/1/2014
IIFLFIN,NA,999.2,4/1/2014
SCIT,NA,1150,4/1/2014
IIFLFIN,NA,1019.81,8/1/2014
IRFC,NA,1098.09,8/1/2014
AICHAMP,BE,14.15,4/1/2014
```

The code I've used for this purpose.

```
data = read.csv('sample.csv', as.is = T)
subdata = data [ data $SERIES=='EQ', ]
```

I want to get only those rows matching **`EQ`** in the **`SERIES`** column, don't want those 'NA' rows spoiling it. `EQ` is just a representative, sometimes I would need some other string matching, maybe even 'NA'.

Please help or any pointers to resolve this niggling issue. 
Best if this can be resolved by base R, otherwise I'm open to using any package. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

NA are not comparable to anything.  You need to also remove all NA values to do this.

```
subdata = data [!is.na(data$SERIES) & data$SERIES=='EQ', ]
```

From `?"=="`:

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA. Missing values can also result when character strings are compared and one is not valid in the current collation locale.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The rows having "NA" are not really NA, rather they have the SERIES variable value as "NA", it also includes values like "N9", "NB", "NC".. etc. 
So those rows ARE of interest and shouldn't be dropped. Also the data.frame shouldn't have any actual NA anywhere, and running is.na removes the rows wrongly tagegd as NA by R.

Not sure If I am able to convey the sense properly. Please let me if you need any clarification.

Comment: If "NA" are not missing values then you need to read with an alternative NA string. `read.csv("sample.csv",na.strings="zzzz")` for example.  In that case you original code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. Setting `na.strings` to some non-occurring string worked great.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
```

## Data

```
data <-
    structure(list(SYMBOL = c("A2ZMES", "IIFLFIN", "SCIT", "IIFLFIN", "IRFC", "AICHAMP"),
                   SERIES = c("EQ", NA, NA, NA, NA, "BE"), 
                   CLOSE = c(10.8, 999.2, 1150, 1019.81, 1098.09, 14.15), 
                   TIMESTAMP = c("4/1/2014", "4/1/2014", "4/1/2014", "8/1/2014", "8/1/2014", "4/1/2014")), 
              .Names = c("SYMBOL", "SERIES", "CLOSE", "TIMESTAMP"), 
              class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

## Solution

```
# filter non missing values

data %>% 
    filter(!is.na(SERIES))

   SYMBOL SERIES CLOSE TIMESTAMP
1  A2ZMES     EQ 10.80  4/1/2014
2 AICHAMP     BE 14.15  4/1/2014
```